# How to check if a record exists before inserting a lot of data into a database?

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I've looked around a bit but most of the answers pertain to stored procedures for SQL which I cannot interface, or predetermined values like `"Select count(*) from MyTable where id = 1"`

I'm currently using this bit of code block that got a little help from another question. As you can see, the Access database gets inserted into as a whole. Assuming I add another column to the table called ID that is intended to be unique, how can I determine if it has already been inserted?

```
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(Con))
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand())
{
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    conn.Open();
    for (int i = 0; i <= DGVExcel.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        cmd.CommandText =
            "Insert INTO ACTB (FirstName, LastName, GrossIncome, LessTNT, TaxableIncomeCE, TaxableIncomePE, GrossTaxableIncome, LessTE, LessPPH, NetTax, TaxDue, HeldTaxCE, HeldTaxPE, TotalTax) " +
            "VALUES(@First, @Last, @Gross, @LessTNT, @TCI, @ADDTI, @GTI, @LessTE, @LessPPH, @LessNTI, @TD, @TWCE, @TWPE, @TATW)";
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", Convert.ToInt32(txtID.Text));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@First", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Last", DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gross", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTNT",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TCI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADDTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GTI", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[6].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessTE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessPPH",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LessNTI",
            Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[9].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TD", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[10].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWCE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[11].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TWPE", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[12].Value));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TATW", Convert.ToDouble(DGVExcel.Rows[i].Cells[13].Value));
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Here's what I thought up so far:

```
cmd = ("If not exists( Select*from ACTB where ID = @ID....
```

ah damn I forgot I can't predetermine the value. It has to pull from the Datagridview somehow, since these are a lot of rows, I cant simply specify DGV.Rows[i].Cells[1], right?

EDIT:
I failed to imply in the post that I need to know explicitly if there is a similar field in the DB from the Datagridview because in a separate function I then add their values to the original in the DB. No duplicates but their values update. Like Employee1 has 10000 income salary, table sees duplicate, adds it's versions income salary to the original in the DB where the fields match.

Comment: I don't think Db will not add duplicate values for unique fields. You will get an exception.

Comment: It wont? Hmmm, well I haven't implemented the Idea I thought up earlier but I have a question @Prajwal, would the entire query break if it reaches this exception since I'm adding the contents of the entire DataGridView into the database. Ideally, it would leave out the fields that have an exception and insert the fields that do. Another scenario that I failed to imply in the post is, I need to know explicitly if there is a similar field in the DB from the Datagridview and then add their values to the original in the DB.

Comment: You can always check using different query. try to select an item using that unique ID and if it returns 0 rows its fine. Else don't add it.

Answer (score -1):

One option would be to include a WHERE clause in your statement that looks for the @ID.

```
WHERE ACTB.ID <> @ID
```

This is assuming that ID is not an Auto-Increment field generated by the insert. If it is then you could use other fields in the WHERE clause such as FirstName and LastName

Comment: While I do have an autoincremented ID field. The ID field I mention is something that is specific to the employee and is entirely unique. I'm not sure what your query does exactly.